# Measure sf polygon as line segments

Tags: r, polygon, r-sf

I want to return the dimensions of some gridded polygons. I know the overall area of the polygons, but I would like to have the height and width as well for some calculations. The polygons are sf objects and I wanted to convert them into multiline objects and then just take the length of each line. I can't figure out how to do this, but assume there is a built in function in the sf package for this.

For some sample code:

```
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
poly <- nc[5,] # object five chosen at random for testing
```

Now I just want `poly` to be converted to a series of lines, and then be able to take the length of those lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the lines? The polygon boundaries?

Comment: The lines would be the polygon boundary

Comment: `sf::st_length( nc )` gives you the length in metres of the boundaries, is this what you're after?

Comment: You want the height and width as well? Aligned to your coordinate reference system? Use `st_bbox`? If you really do want to convert to line segments, use `st_cast(poly, "MULTILINESTRING)` and then maybe cast that to LINESTRING.

Comment: `st_bbox` gets after what I am looking for. This returns the x and y min/max and I can then calculate the difference. Yes I was looking for the height and width specifically. @Spacedman